# python pandas multiindex to array of matrices

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a pandas DataFrame - assume, for example, that it contains some rolling covariance estimates:

```
df = #some data
rolling_covariance = df.rolling(window=100).cov()
```

If the data has `n` columns then `rolling_covariance` will contain `m` n by n matrices, where `m` is the number of rows in `df`.

Is there quick/one-liner to transform `rolling_covariance` into a numpy array of matrices? For example you can access individual rows in `rolling_covariance` using `iloc`, you can also iterate through all of the first level of the multiindex and extract the data that way - but I'd like something fast and simple if available